# Cannot load class from assembly

Tags: c#, class, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a `dll` file which contains following *class*.

```
public class UnityContainerConfig : IContainer
{
    private IUnityContainer _unityContainer;
    public UnityContainerConfig()
    {
        _unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    }

    public void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

    }
}
```

Now I want to load this class from assembly in another project.

```
AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(path);
Assembly iocConfigurationAssembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
Type configFile = iocConfigurationAssembly.GetType("UnityContainerConfig");
```

The assembly is loaded correctly but i received `null` value when i try to use `GetType`.

Comment: From msdn: `The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the full name, including the namespace.

From msdn entry for [Assembly.GetType Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The name parameter includes the namespace but not the assembly.